# Recurrence equation with upper and lower boundary condition

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

A very natural set up for recurrence equations is the following:
$$ s(0) = 0 $$
$$ s(k) = A \ s(k-1) + B $$
$$ s(M) = A \ s(M-1), $$
where $0 \le A,B \le 1$ and $0 < k < M$.
We can omit the third equation to find that for $k = 0, 1, \dots, M-2$
\begin{align*}
s(k+1) &= A^{k+1}s(0) + \sum_{i=0}^k A^i B \\
&=B \ \sum_{i=0}^k A^i \\
&= B \frac{1-A^{k+1}}{1-A}.
\end{align*}
However, how can we impose now the condition $s(M) = A \ s(M-1)$?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear of what you're supposed to do. Are you trying to get a general expression for the terms in the recurrence relation? If so, you're nearly done because the middle equation only holds for k=0,...M-1. You have that $s(M-1) = B\frac{1-A^{M-1}}{1-A}$ and so $s(M) = AB\frac{1-A^{M-1}}{1-A}$.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence you have is of the first order, so you can only impose one condition. I.e., either fix $s(0)$, or state the restriction on $s(M)$.